# Tag for the new game FIFA World

Tags: support, tags, tag-creation

I would like to request a new tag "fifa-world" as well as a retag of the question I just asked here: [What does the finesse modifier do in FIFA World?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/177729/what-does-the-finesse-modifier-do-in-fifa-world)

FIFA World is a new online game from EA that is f2p on Origin.  The resources available for the game are very sparse, and searching for game documentation is difficult due to the extensive use of the keywords "FIFA" and "World" in seemingly countless unrelated sites.

If anyone is able to help with the question I have posted, I have a number of additional questions I would like to ask about this game.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Done. In the future, you can also just ask one of the regulars in Chat on [The Bridge](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge), or flag it for Moderator attention, rather than making a Meta post.

Comment: Thanks very much!  That was super fast!